# Is there a significant difference in population percentages

Tags: statistics

The question is, "If an 85% confidence interval (CI) for the difference between the population of A Students (Pa) and B Students (Pb) is   -15.8% < Pa-Pb < -7.9%, is there a ***significant*** difference between the population percentages?

Wasn't sure where to go with this.  I know that if the CI includes zero then there is no significant difference.  This interval does NOT include 0, so can I conclude that there IS a significant difference?  This would not seem to use the 85% CI value at all.  Not sure where to go with my thinking on this statistics problem.

Answer (score 1):

The confidence interval/hypothesis test relationship goes that if 0 is not in the C% confidence interval for a difference, then there is a significance difference at the (100-C)% significance level. So if 0 is not in your 85% confidence interval, then there is a significant difference at the 15% confidence level.

I suspect the person who wrote the question is asking if it's significant at the 5% significance level, which would correspond to a 95% confidence interval. In that case, we'll need to convert to a 95% confidence interval.

The usual confidence interval for the difference in proportions is given by:
$$
\text{CI endpoints} = \hat{p_a} - \hat{p_b} \pm z^*\sqrt{\frac{\hat{p_a}(1-\hat{p_a})}{n_a}+\frac{\hat{p_a}(1-\hat{p_a})}{n_a}}
$$
Note that this formula gives the confidence interval in proportions, rather than percentages.

To explain the notation:
$\hat{p_a}$ is the sample proportion from group $a$,
$\hat{p_b}$ is the sample proportion from group $b$,
$z^*$ is the critical value from the standard normal distribution for your confidence level,
$n_a$ is the sample size from group $a$,
and $n_b$ is the sample size from group $b$.

The square root part of the formula is often called the "standard error", and the part after the $\pm$ is usually called the "margin of error". That is, we can rewrite the formula in these ways:
$$
\text{CI endpoints} = \hat{p_a} - \hat{p_b} \pm z^*SE \text{, where } SE = \sqrt{\frac{\hat{p_a}(1-\hat{p_a})}{n_a}+\frac{\hat{p_a}(1-\hat{p_a})}{n_a}}\\
\text{CI endpoints} = \hat{p_a} - \hat{p_b} \pm ME \text{, where } ME = z^*\sqrt{\frac{\hat{p_a}(1-\hat{p_a})}{n_a}+\frac{\hat{p_a}(1-\hat{p_a})}{n_a}}
$$
The margin of error tells you how far from the centre the ends of the confidence interval are. Also, twice the margin of error tells you how wide the confidence interval is. In our case, the width of the confidence interval is 15.8% - 7.9% = 7.8% = 0.079. Thus the margin of error is 0.079/2 = 0.0395.

The $z^*$ value for 85% confidence we would get from software or a table (using Microsoft Excel and the formula `=NORM.S.INV(0.5+0.85/2)` I get the value of 1.46. The $z^*$ value for 95% confidence is 1.96.

Since $ME = z^* SE$, we can figure out the standard error from the margin of error:
$$
\begin{align}
ME &= z^* SE\\
SE &= \frac{ME}{z^*}\\
&= \frac{0.0395}{1.46}\\
&= 0.02705
\end{align}
$$

Now if we want to convert to a 95% confidence interval we can find the new margin of error:
$$
\begin{align}
\text{New } ME &= z^*SE\\
&= 1.96 \times 0.02705
&= 0.0530
\end{align}
$$

Note that the centre of your confidence interval is $\hat{p_a} - \hat{p_b}$. For your original confidence interval this is the average of the two endpoints, so $\hat{p_a} - \hat{p_b} = (-0.0158 - 0.079)/2 = -0.1185$. Thus the endpoints of your 95% confidence interval are:
$$
\begin{align}
\text{95% CI endpoints} &= \hat{p_a} - \hat{p_b} \pm ME\\
&= -0.1185 \pm 0.0530\\
&= -0.1715, -0.0655\\
&= -17.15\%, -6.55\%
\end{align}
$$

So 0 is not in the 95% confidence interval and so we conclude that there is a significant difference at the 5% significance level.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed explanation. I find the excel tip especially helpful.  I kinda thought that the question was looking for a yes/no answer, but perhaps the question (from my community college stats online databank) has mis-asked the question.